# jQuery, get datas in AJAX (done) then, display them as star (error)

Tags: jquery

I'm using a star rating, 100% working except when i insert values with javascript :

**EXAMPLE : http://www.gamer-certified.fr/test.html**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

jQuery.ajax({
      type: "get",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: "http://www.gamer-certified.fr/export/widget.php",
      data: {demandeur: "esl" },
      cache: true, 
      success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){

        var obj = null, length = data.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

            widget = "<span class='stars'>"+(data[i].qualite / 2)+"</span>" // automatic not working
            widget = "<span class='stars'>4</span>" // manually not working
            jQuery('#gamer-certified'+i).html(widget);
            }    
    } 
});
});
</script>
```

The only thing is working is putting directly the data in the span value OUTSIDE the widget +=

```
<span class="stars">4</span> // is working when directly put on the HTML side
```

**EXAMPLE : http://www.gamer-certified.fr/test.html**

Thanks !

Comment: What are you using to do cross-domain Ajax successfully?

Comment: the data are provided in JSON-P , so i wrote a parser, which look basicly like : widget += data[i].value;

Comment: I checked the site in firefox and firebug keeps giving this error "jQuery.sprintf is not a function
[Break on this error] hours, esl.getMinutes(), esl.getSeconds() ".

Comment: yes, these errors occurs sometimes. Try reloading. I can't do nothing, i don't have the special right to do it. Theses errors are not the cause of the plugin who don't work for values recieved from another domain, because it's working for the values entered manually.

Comment: If this works for values entered manually, are you sure your custom parser is definitely giving the correctly formatted values?

Comment: ofc, i was thinking of the .live attribute, because imagine that the rating star plugin is loaded before the parser write the values in the page. Do you get what i'm trying to point out ?

Comment: Where in your code do you have an action that isn't working?  Live is created to bind an event handler to all future matches to that selector.

Comment: the data i recieved are not transformed into stars. That's the only problem

Comment: the post has been updated with a lot lot better explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out why manually entered data works and the data which you receive does not, you need to figure out what is different between the manual data and the entered data.  Is it the timing of a jQuery event?  Is it the formatting of the data?  Once you find this difference, make sure that you address it using the correct means.

**EDIT**: based on a review of the code, the `$.stars()` call happens on `$(document).ready()`, while the content is retrieved after that.  Call `$.stars() in the callback, not before.

Comment: i just updated the post, and I explain a lot lot lot much better !

Comment: @Tristan - have you tried wrapping the calculation for the stars in ()?

Comment: And you've done an `alert` or (with Firebug) `console.log()` to make sure the values are numeric and what you expect?

Comment: yeah the value are numeric, look at : http://www.gamer-certified.fr/test.html  the first value is from the ajax request. It's a numeric value. The second one, i typed manually 4. So this is a numeric value too, but no stars ='(

Comment: You need to make sure the `span.stars` call happens AFTER the content is inserted into the DOM, as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will sove your problem, but there's a `+` missing before `0`:

`widget = "<span class='stars'>"+0+(data[i].qualite / 2)+"</span>"`

Comment: i'm sorry, it's not solving my problem, it was a mistake i did when i update the post